# Typescript lint marking errors

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have a qustion. I upgreade my packgages.json and after that my tslint mark every soft-mistake to underscore red. When i said soft-mistake i mean a too long line or to many spaces or tabs. Those mistakes was marked by green underscore befor update. Can anybody help my with configurate tsliny ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .eslintrc files you would have json object. Search for key rules. Now here you would have rules specified for lint to evaluate your code against. Each rule will have a number 0 or 1 or 2, wherein :

```
"off" or 0 - turn the rule off
"warn" or 1 - turn the rule on as a warning (doesn’t affect exit code)
"error" or 2 - turn the rule on as an error (exit code is 1 when triggered)
```

You can change the number as per your convenience to modify the rule.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your ts lint configuration. Open your `tslint.json` file and change the following property to `false` or increase its length :

```
"max-line-length": [
  false,
  140
],
```